# Different icons for App Icon and App store

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

let me summarise the issue, I have one app in a flutter, and I need different logos for the app on iPhone and on app store IOS.

so, is it possible to set the app icon and app store icon differently for IOS?

Answer (score 0):

you can release one time your application with android icons.

and next time release your application with ios icons.

this path you can go there and change logos:

```
/android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: i'm not talking about play store console